# Dockerfile can COPY files into a declared volume, but RUN cannot create files?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've been expiriencing a bit of weird behavior regarding volumes.  We have a container which contains a database, and is expected to bind mount folders from the host which contain the data.  I'm trying to create a child container which ships with test data, as it is just used for testing.

This requires that during the build step, some data is copied off the host machine, and then some scripts run which create additional files.  I've noticed however though when I have a look at the running container, only the copied files exist, and the ones created by scripts do not.  I've boiled down the steps to the following docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial-20180112.1

VOLUME /test

COPY /test/copydir/copyfile.txt /test/copydir/copyfile.txt

RUN mkdir -p /test/mkdir && \
    touch /test/mkdir/touch.txt
```

Note that when I bash into the running container and do an

```
ls -l /test
```

I only get the 'copydir' folder.  If I run an ls in my dockerfile however, I see that both folders exist.

What's going on here?

edit:

For additional context, the following prints out that both directories exist:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial-20180112.1

VOLUME /test

COPY /test/copydir/copyfile.txt /test/copydir/copyfile.txt

RUN mkdir -p /test/mkdir && \
    touch /test/mkdir/touch.txt && \
    ls -l /test
```

But the following only shows that copydir exists:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial-20180112.1

VOLUME /test

COPY /test/copydir/copyfile.txt /test/copydir/copyfile.txt

RUN mkdir -p /test/mkdir && \
    touch /test/mkdir/touch.txt

RUN ls -l /test
```

Comment: What is the command you are using to start the container?

Comment: docker build --rm -f Dockerfile -t test:Latest .
;docker run -it --name test1 test:Latest bash

Comment: This the command to build the image. what is the `docker run` command you are using?

Comment: Not sure if you commented whilst I was editing: the run is in the same comment after the ;

Comment: Try adding `&& ls /test/mkdir/` in your Dockerfile after `touch /test/mkdir/touch.txt` and see what it prints.

Comment: I've added some more information to the bottom of my post re that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the exact explanation of this but when you build an image with a Dockerfile it will make the lightest image possible. When you use RUN you don't make data persistant but you only do an action that will give a result that will not stay in the image.

Note that apt-get and yum commands make installations persist. It's kinda weird.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking.  I can live with either COPY not working, or RUN working, but it just seems inconsistent otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial-20180112.1

RUN mkdir -p /test
COPY /test/copydir/copyfile.txt /test/copydir/copyfile.txt

RUN mkdir -p /test/mkdir && \
    touch /test/mkdir/touch.txt

VOLUME /test
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible.  The example I provided was cut down for clarity, in actuality the volume is defined by a parent image, and it's not practical to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

In a remark you said "The example I provided was cut down for clarity, in actuality the volume is defined by a parent image." That would relate the problem to the case that is not possible to undeclare a volume entry for a derived image. If that is possible (e.g. using [docker-copyedit](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit)) then your problem may go away. ;)